# Update password Only After Conditional is Met in NodeJS and ExpressJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, mern

I'm trying to create a component in which I request to the user his current password and two iinputs that need to match to change its password.

So far, I created my route as follow:

```
// @route       POST api/profiles/edit-password
// @description Update user password
// @access      Private
// @task        ALMOST DONE - NEEDS TO AVOID PASSWORD UPDATING IF NULL
router.post(
  '/edit-password',
  [
    auth,
    [
      check('old_password', 'Old Password is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('old_password', 'Old Password does not match')
        .exists(),
      check('password', 'New Password is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty(),
      check('new_password', 'Confirm Password is required')
        .not()
        .isEmpty()
    ]
  ],
  async (req, res) => {
    const errors = validationResult(req);
    // Check for errors
    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
      return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    // Destructure
    const {
      old_password,
      password,
      new_password,
    } = req.body;

    // Build profile object
    const profileFields = {};
    profileFields.user = req.user.id;
    if (password === new_password) {
      // Encrypt Password
      passwordEncrypt = password;
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      profileFields.password = await bcrypt.hash(passwordEncrypt, salt);
    }

    try {

      let formOldPassword = old_password; // req.body.old_password can be used as well.
      let loggedPassword = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('password');

      // Old password input with password stored in DB
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(formOldPassword, loggedPassword);

      console.log(isMatch ? 'yes' : 'no');

      // In case old password input does not match with password stored in DB, prevent from updating password
      if (!isMatch) {
        return res
          .status(400)
          .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Invalid credentials' }] });
      }

      let profile = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, profileFields, { new: true });

      return res.json(profile);


    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err.message);
      res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
  }
);
```

I'm passing three inputs from a form that I have in a functional component, those inputs are:

- old_password
- password
- new_password

After that I build an empty object that I will use to update said values that correspond to the user requesting it. After that, I'm making a condition that if both the new_password and confirm_password do match, it should encrypt the password using hash(Here it is where I am assuming the error is caused; I might be wrong):

```
if (password === new_password) {
      // Encrypt Password
      passwordEncrypt = password;
      const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
      profileFields.password = await bcrypt.hash(passwordEncrypt, salt);
    }
```

Then I move to make a call to the database to get the password that corresponds to the loggedIn user and compare its stored password with the data submitted from the form:

```
let formOldPassword = old_password; // req.body.old_password can be used as well.
let loggedPassword = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('password');

// Old password input with password stored in DB
const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(formOldPassword, loggedPassword);
```

Now both inputs must match but in case they don't do, return a 400 http error. In case everything so far has been a success, update the loggedIn user data.

```
// In case old password input does not match with password stored in DB, prevent from updating password
if (!isMatch) {
  return res
    .status(400)
    .json({ errors: [{ msg: 'Invalid credentials' }] });
}

let profile = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.user.id, profileFields, { new: true });

return res.json(profile);
```

The unexpected(the error) output that I get in the console is this:

```
Illegal arguments: string, object
```

Any idea in how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing a string new password with a object (instead of String) . Try below and print the old password

```
   try {
            const userObj = await User.findById(req.user.id);
            const oldPassword = userObj.password;
             console.log("OLD password" + password);
            //Then do your comparision logic
        } catch (err) {
            console.log('error occured' +err);   
        }
```

Comment: I actually did not follow your code but I guided myself. You see that I have my let `loggedPassword = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('password');`, right? Well I kept it that way but I used `loggedPassword.password`.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is you are trying to

```
bcrypt.compare(formOldPassword, loggedPassword);

formOldPassword = req.body.old_password ----> String

loggedPassword = await User.findById(req.user.id).select('password') ---> Hash
```